# Парсинг json to html

Tags: html, json, парсер

Есть какой-нибудь несложный способ распарсить большой кусок json-а ещё и с комментариями в html таблицу? (по типу имя параметра, тип, комментарий-назначение)
Поиск по просторам интернета не дал результата т.к комментарии не поддерживаются.

Писать  парсер самой используя регулярки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON по стандарту не может содержать комментарии. 
да и если вы распарсите их (что возможно), нужно и определить их позиции. 
а комментарии можно хоть куда поставить между строками кода.

Comment: Знаю что не может, ну раз нельзя, то ладно.